# Flask app not displaying predictions made from CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, keras

Hello I am trying to create a web app from the CIFAR-10 dataset but the app is not able to go to the prediction route it is just stuck on loading.
I trained the model in google colab and downloaded the h5 file 
the home page is showing and the file uploader is also working the problem is just that the prediction are not showing.
I am new to stackoverflow so kindly overlook my mistakes while asking a question.
Here is the code I used:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
import sys
import os
import glob
import re
import numpy as np

# # Keras

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model


# Flask utils
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

app = Flask(__name__)

MODEL_PATH = 'final_model.h5'

classes = ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 
            'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck'] 

# Load your trained model
model = load_model(MODEL_PATH)   

def load_image(filepath):
    # load the image
    img = image.load_img(filepath, target_size=(32, 32))
    # convert to array
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    # reshape into a single sample with 3 channels
    img = np.expand_dims(img,axis=0)
    return img

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    # Main page
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        filepath = os.path.join(basepath, 'uploads', secure_filename(f.filename))
        f.save(filepath)

        img = load_image(filepath)
        pred = model.predict_classes(img)
        result = str(classes[pred])
        return result
    return None
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

my index.html file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block content %}

<h2>Image Classifier</h2>

<div>
    <form id="upload-file" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="imageUpload" class="upload-label">
            Choose...
        </label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="imageUpload" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg">
    </form>

    <div class="image-section" style="display:none;">
        <div class="img-preview">
            <div id="imagePreview">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " id="btn-predict">Predict!</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="loader" style="display:none;"></div>

    <h3 id="result">
        <span> </span>
    </h3>

</div>

{% endblock %}
'''
PLease help me.
```

Answer (score 0):

i  think  you  should  add  action="http://localhost:5000/predict"  in  form  tag

Comment: There was no error it was just stuck on loading it was not going to the prediction url